# selenium - created variable but doesn't seem available

Tags: file-upload, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to set a variable `$import_location` so that I can set it once for many uses and not hard-code it into each test case that is doing file uploads.

I have the variable set OK with the store command.

I am trying to use it on the uploads screen but keep getting the literal ${variable name}

How can I set the import location to be the variable that I've set above?

Comment: How are you finding the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hadn't run the actual 'variable setting' script.  One I had run it and created the variable I was able to use it OK.